# Create multiplepages pdf with imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagick, multipage

I need create PDF with Imagick and I need multipage file. How to add page?

I have to use Imagick - not TCPDF, FPDF etc.

format of the page is SRA3 - 45 cm x 32 cm

```
<?php

$pdf = new Imagick();

$pdf->newImage(45*300/2.54,32*300/2.54, 'white');

header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=downloaded.pdf");

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('white');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1*300/2.54);
$draw->setStrokeColor('rgb(0, 0, 0)');
$draw->rectangle(10*300/2.54,10*300/2.54,35*300/2.54,22*300/2.54);

$pdf->drawImage($draw);
$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
echo $pdf->getImageBlob();

$pdf->newImage(45*300/2.54,32*300/2.54, 'white');

$draw->setStrokeWidth(1*300/2.54);
$draw->setStrokeColor('rgb(0, 0, 255)');
$draw->rectangle(10*300/2.54,10*300/2.54,35*300/2.54,22*300/2.54);

$pdf->drawImage($draw);


$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
echo $pdf->getImageBlob();

?>
```